# How to use both 'include' and 'attributes' in 'findByPk' statement in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, orm, sequelize.js

How to use both 'include' and 'attributes' in 'findByPk' statement in Sequelize. This is my code:

```
exports.findOne = (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id;

  User.findByPk(id, 
    
    {
      include: ["roles"] 
    }, 
    {
      attributes: {
         exclude: ['password']
      }
    }
    )
      .then(data => {
        res.send({"data": data, "resultCode": 1, "message": ""});
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
          message:
            err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving users."
        });
      });;

}
```

But it only works when I use 1 of 2 only.
If I just use: `attributes: { exclude: ['password']}` the result is as follows:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "admin",
        "email": "admin@gmail.com",
        "createdAt": "2021-09-27T04:22:56.660Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-09-27T04:22:56.660Z"
    },
    "resultCode": 1,
    "message": ""
}
```

If I just use: `{include: ["roles"]}` so the result is as follows

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "admin",
        "email": "admin@gmail.com",
        "password": "$2a$08$m54ioIwzpZRVC9/HqkHyqezOornjmvT9pDEJcOhHbNcSmLOfw3Sg.",
        "createdAt": "2021-09-27T04:22:56.660Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-09-27T04:22:56.660Z",
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "moderator",
                "createdAt": "2021-09-27T04:20:46.956Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-09-27T04:20:46.956Z",
                "user_roles": {
                    "createdAt": "2021-09-27T04:22:56.791Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2021-09-27T04:22:56.791Z",
                    "roleId": 2,
                    "userId": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "admin",
                "createdAt": "2021-09-27T04:20:46.956Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-09-27T04:20:46.956Z",
                "user_roles": {
                    "createdAt": "2021-09-27T04:22:56.791Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2021-09-27T04:22:56.791Z",
                    "roleId": 3,
                    "userId": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "resultCode": 1,
    "message": ""
}
```

How to use both in my code? Because I dont want to show 'password' field in my result but I want to show the roles of user in my result. How to do like that. Thanks you in advanced

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Options should be in 1 object like this.

```
User.findByPk(id, 
{
  include: ["roles"],
  attributes: {
     exclude: ['password']
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks you so much